# First argument to append must be slice

Tags: go

I am having trouble calling the `append` function in Go

```
type Dog struct {
    color  string
}

type Dogs []Dog
```

I want to append "Dog" into "Dogs".

I tried doing this

```
Dogs = append(Dogs, Dog)
```

But I get this error

```
First argument to append must be slice; have *Dogs
```

Edit:
Also, if I want to check if this Dog contains the color "white", for example. How would I call this?

```
 if Dog.color.contains("white") { 
    //then append this Dog into Dogs
 }
```

Comment: `Dogs` is a type, not a variable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Dogs is a type not a variable, you probably meant to:

```
var Dogs []Dog
```

Comment: Lets say I have to use what is given, how do I make it a variable so I can call it in Append?

Comment: You can create a variable from `type Dogs []Dog` , for example: `var myDogs Dogs`

Answer (score 7):

As friends says it should not be a type, here is example can be helpful:

```
// Create empty slice of struct pointers.
Dogs := []*Dog{}
// Create struct and append it to the slice.
dog := new(Dog)
dog.color = "black"
Dogs = append(Dogs, dog)
```